# Nokogiri return empty array parsing an xml file

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, screen-scraping

Nothing worked when I tried the first time, so i decided to try with the exemple given by nokogiri I took their xml doc listing some characters of sitcoms:

Edit : After having read the comment it seems that it comes from an issue of my environment or something like that specific to me : 2.2.0p0 nokogiri : 1.6.6.2

```xml
[demo.xml]
<root>
  <sitcoms>
    <sitcom>
      <name>Married with Children</name>
      <characters>
        <character>Al Bundy</character>
        <character>Bud Bundy</character>
        <character>Marcy Darcy</character>
      </characters>
    </sitcom>
    <sitcom>
      <name>Perfect Strangers</name>
      <characters>
        <character>Larry Appleton</character>
        <character>Balki Bartokomous</character>
      </characters>
    </sitcom>
  </sitcoms>
  <dramas>
    <drama>
      <name>The A-Team</name>
      <characters>
        <character>John "Hannibal" Smith</character>
        <character>Templeton "Face" Peck</character>
        <character>"B.A." Baracus</character>
        <character>"Howling Mad" Murdock</character>
      </characters>
    </drama>
  </dramas>
</root>
```

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'


@doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("demo.xml"))
@doc.xpath("//character")
```

and runned ruby test.rb but this gave no results but no error so i tried the same in irb which returned me

```shell
 => []
```

I'm sure it's something silly but I have no clue and i'm not finding the answer anywhere (that's why i'm thinking that's silly) :) Thx to you

Comment: I can't replicate this behavior with ruby 2.1.0 and Nokogiri 1.6.6.2. What value do you get when calling `@doc.root.name` ?

Comment: I just ran the code you gave with the xml you gave, and I'm seeing different results. I get a non-empty array.

Comment: @doc.root.name   give me this => demo_crawl.rb:6:in `<main>': undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) -- so it may be an issue with my environement or somehting specific to me Ruby : 2.2.0p0 nokogiri : 1.6.6.2

Comment: Do you have `[demo.xml]` at the top of the file? If so remove it, it’s not part of the XML.

Comment: I knew it was silly... Damn I feel stupid (thought it was a comment) Should i post the answer ?